# Anyone help me to resolve this error in Invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error 
occurred on a send.## Heading ##
At \Desktop\T.ps1:27 char:7
+ $CS = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri https://XXXX ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 
   ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the script T.ps1 line: 27 char: 7, and it is related to the Invoke-ResMethod cmdlet. I'll give you an example on how to use Invoke-RestMethod.

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "place the dns or ip you want to request" -Method (POST or Get)

Working example to request google:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.google.com" -Method GET
```

This must return the html code of google's web page

Comment: Am trying in the same format before some time I got the response then am getting this error event I forced TLS12

Comment: What if the issue is on the server side ? Meaning: Maybe the server is closing the connection or dropping the request for some reason

Comment: Some time same script is working few times am getting this error. How can I start troubleshoot this from the target server side??